# Number of way to invite my friends over for dinner on 5 nights

Tags: combinatorics

Okay so here's the full problem followed what I'm thinking:

> **Problem**: How many successive ways are there to invite one of four different friends over for dinner on five successive night s.t no friend is invite more than three times?

Now here's the though process I'm going down:

> We proceed by cases, adding up the cases at the end
>
> **Case 1**: 1 friend for 3 nights, 1 friend for 2 nights
>
> Let's denote the friends as $f_i$ where $1\leq i\leq 4$. If $f_1$ eats dinner at the house for 3 nights, that leaves either $f_2$ for two nights, or $f_3$ or $f_4$. Thus, there are 3 arrangements if $f_1$ eats dinner 3 nights. It follows similarly if we consider $f_2$ for the spot of 3 nights, or $f_3$ or $f_4$. Thus, there are $$12{5 \choose 3}{2 \choose 2}$$
>   arrangements possible.
>
> **Case 2**: 1 friend for 3 nights, 1 friend for 1 night, 1 friend for 1 night
>
> If $f_1$ eats dinner at the house 3 nights, we have $f_2$ one night, $f_3$ one night. Or we have $f_2$ one night, $f_4$ one night. Or we have $f_3$ one night, $f_4$ one night. Thus, with $f_1$ on 3 nights, we have 3 ways to choose. The subcases of $f_2-f_4$ follow similiarly, so we have $$12{5 \choose 3}{2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}$$

Am I on the right track or does there need to be some revision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning looks correct.

I think it might be simpler to eliminate the cases where one friend is invited for four or five nights.

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry I'm very new to combinatorics :\

Comment: The total number of ways is $4^5$=1024.  From that, subtract how many ways you can invite the same friend five times.  Also subtract how many ways you can invite one friend four times and another friend once.  Both calculations are similar to what you have shown us, but the good thing is there are only two, fairly simple, calculations.

Comment: Sorry to respond so late! I got caught up with other work. Hmm...since we have 4 different friends and 5 different nights, wouldn't the nights act as 'boxes' in which to place our friends $\implies 5^4$ total number of ways (since we have n=5 nights and r=4 friends, using the formula $n^r$)? I think I'm beginning to piece this complement method together :D

Comment: If what I said was correct, I got *Total # of arrangements (with restrictions)* = $5^4 - 64=561$. If $4^5$ is correct, I think the 64 stays, I would just get $960$ instead.